# MySQL query to select maximum time value for maximum date for each customer

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have a table named `Transaction` for customer transactions, it contains:

```
CustomerID, 
Datetrans (transaction date)
Timetrans (transaction time)
```

I would like to return the max(Datetrans), given that a customer can make two transactions a day; I want to get the max value of Timetrans for that max Datetrans date.

I have tried :

```
SELECT CustomerID, MAX(Datetrans), MAX(Timetrans) FROM Transaction
```

It returns the all time maximum time value from the whole table, not depending on the maximum date.
I have also tried some joins (outer and inner), alternating max(Datetrans) and max(Timetrans) and it didn't go through for some reason.
PLEASE HELP!

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Store dates and times as a single entity

Answer (score 0):

First, you would need a `GROUP BY` to get more than one row:

```
SELECT CustomerID, MAX(Datetrans), MAX(Timetrans)
FROM Transaction
GROUP BY CustomerId;
```

But what I really think you want is the most recent date/time combination.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from transaction t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from transaction t2
                where t2.customerid = t.customerid
               ) and
      t.time = (select max(t2.time)
                from transaction t3
                where t3.customerid = t.customerid and
                      t3.date = t.date
               );
```

There are other methods.  This would be simpler if you stored a single date/time value (and you could combine them for the `max()`) or if MySQL had window functions.  Yet another method uses tuples:

```
select t.*
from transaction t
where not exists (select 1
                  from transaction t2
                  where t2.customerid = t.customerid and
                        (t2.date, t2.time) > (t.date, t.time)
                 );
```

or:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where (t.date, t.time) = (select t2.date, t2.time
                          from transaction t2
                          where t2.customerid = t.customerid
                          order by t2.date desc, t2.time desc
                          limit 1
                         );
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I had used the group by statement, no worries haha. I find the very first answer so simple and super effective; and it's true that I haven't thought through your way of doing it. Thank you for your precious time to give an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single simpler query by converting the two separate fields into a single timestamp field.  I don't know anything about performance though.

```
SELECT customerID, DATE(maxTime) as datetrans, TIME(maxTime) as timeTrans 
FROM (
    select customerID, max(Timestamp(dateTrans, timeTrans)) as maxTime
      from transactions
      group by customerID) as lastCustomerTrans
```

The only reason you need the outer query is to convert the timestamp back into a date and time.

[Link to SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8b1c0/3)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much good sir. I've just spent over 48H trying to figure this out.